# How to append data to specific column Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

FinalFrame:

`Time | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | ...`

and df (Where weekday is the current day, whether it be monday tuesday etc):

`WEEKDAY`

I want to append the weekday's data to the correct column. I will need to constantly keep appending weekdays data as weeks go by. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: I tried merging, it didnt make too much sense, i couldnt get it to work the way i wanted/needed it to

Answer (score 0):

You can add index of week days instead of their name. For example, 
`weekdays = ['Mon', Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri','Sat', 'Sun']`
`Time | 0 | 1 | 2 ....`

Answer (score 0):

So the way you could do it isolates the series by saying weekday[whatever day you are looking at .append.